# AJAX/JSON with possible Jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, event-handling

I am trying to make it so when the user clicks on the name of a person in the list, the box of data on the right side of the screen fills with the description from my JSON file.

I want to make it so that clicking any list item runs an actual AJAX request. The data returned from that request must then be used to fill the box on the right side of the page.

Any ideas or previous thread you could lead me to would be very appreciated.  I've tried many things and have not succeeded.

Can I somehow make each word on the list a clickable element? Maybe with event listener?

Thanks,
Heres my code which is is 3 separate files whis are "html file, javascript file and a json file"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<hmtl lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>AJAX</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="jquery.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
        <script src="ajax.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="loaded-data"></div>
      <div id="result-box"></div>
    </body>
</hmtl>

/* ajax.javascript file */
'use strict';

$(function() {

    let request = $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url : 'people.json',
      dataType: 'json',
    });

    request.done(function(data) {
      let list = data.body.list;
      let resultBox = $('#result-box');
      let unorderedList = $('<ul>');
      resultBox.append(unorderedList);
      console.log(data);


      for (let person of list) {
        let listItem = $('<li>');
        listItem.text(person.name);
        listItem.attr('data-url', person.links[0].href);
        unorderedList.append(listItem);
      }

      });

      request.fail(function(response) {
      console.log('ERROR: ' + response.statusText);

      });
    });

{
"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people.json"},{"rel":"parent","href":"http://www.philart.net/api.json"}],
"head":{"title":"People","type":"listnav"},
"body":{
"list":[
{"name":"Adam","links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/325.json"}]},
{"name":"Abigail Adams","links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/157.json"}]},
{"name":"John Adams","links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/410.json"}]},
{"name":"Samuel Adams","links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/439.json"}]},
{"name":"Lin Zexu","links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/347.json"}]},
{"name":"James A. Zimble","links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/345.json"}]},
{"name":"Doris Zimmerman","links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/171.json"}]}
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a handler like this:

```
let displayPersonData = (person) => {
  console.log(person)
}
```

Then, while rendering list of person, you add event listener like below:

```
for (let person of list) {
    let listItem = $('<li>');
    listItem.text(person.name);
    listItem.attr('data-url', person.links[0].href);
    unorderedList.append(listItem);

    listItem.on('click', () => {
      displayPersonData(person)
    });
}
```

You can add class to `<li>` tags so they act like hyperlink. And customize `displayPersonData` to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As [Doug Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658916/dong-nguyen) stated, you will need an event handler.

```
let displayPersonDescription = person => {
   let html = '';
   html += person.links.reduce((a, c) => {
      //put your formating logic in here
      //i.e. 
     return a + `<a href="${c.href}">${c.href}</a>`;
   }, '');

    html += person.body.art.reduce((a, c) => {
      //additional formating logic here
    }, '');
// continue this pattern for all the sections you want to include
//...
// Finally load the data into the loaded-data div
   $("#loaded-data").html(html);
}
```

Here is the updated section of your code to implement the handeler

```
for (let person of list) {

    //clear the loaded data div
    $(#loaded-data).html('');

    let listItem = $('<li>');
    listItem.text(person.name);
    listItem.attr('data-url', person.links[0].href);
    unorderedList.append(listItem);
    listItem.on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: this.dataSet.url,
                dataType: 'json',
            })
            .done(displayPersonDescription(person))
            .fail(failureData => console.log(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(failureData)}`));
    });
}
```